# How to customise sidebar in wordpress and add collapsable menu in that?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, tags, categories

How to customize sidebar in WordPress in a way so all the Catagory and its chiled will be available.
As For Example: In [https://www.w3schools.com](https://w3school)

if we click on top header category lets say HTML, all the html related links will available in left side bar .

I am new to HTML and Css. Could you please give some more information where exactly i can find the html and css file in my wordpress??

Where i can make changes in the WordPress?

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1):

Nested Lists
The Classic and Default WordPress Themes use nested lists to present their sidebar information. Nested lists are a series of unordered lists of information, set inside of each other. Here's a simple example:

```
<ul><!-- open whole list -->
<li>Title of Section One
     <ul>
      <li>Apple</li>
      <li>Orange</li>
      <li>Banana</li>
     </ul>
</li><!-- closing list under section one -->
<li>Title of Section Two
     <ul>
      <li>Beef</li>
      <li>Chicken</li>
      <li>Fish</li>
     </ul>
</li><!-- closing list under section two -->
<li>Title of Section Three
     <ul>
      <li>Carrot</li>
      <li>Celery</li>
     </ul>
</li><!-- closing list under section three -->
</ul><!-- closing whole list -->
```

Each of these nested list "sections" can feature a CSS ID or class to make each one look different or all the same, depending upon how they are styled within the style sheet.

You don't have to use nested lists for your sidebar. That is up to you. If you do use the nested lists as set by example in the WordPress core Themes, you need to know how they work. To learn more about how to style your WordPress nested lists, check out the article on Styling Lists with CSS.

Please you may follow this https://codex.wordpress.org/Customizing_Your_Sidebar

Comment: Thanks Kunal for Your help. I am new to HTML and Css. Could you please give some more information where exactly i can find the html and css file in my wordpress??

Comment: @Jhon: Please login your wp and go to appearance -> edit and go to sidebar.php  file.